# how to cache image using Angularjs ionic?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, caching, ionic-framework

I have home page it contains with list of 2 images i have given controller and Html code.every time home page images loading from backend i want to cache the image in local to avoid every time http request and weekly once or 10 days once i want to check from backend if backend image has changed that time i need to update this cache image . i have followed some example but i could not solve this because i am new to this technology some one help me out to move forward

```js
.controller('TestCtrl', [
    '$scope', '$http', '$location', '$window', '$ionicLoading',
    function($scope, $http, $location, $window, $ionicLoading) {
        
        $scope.find = function() {
      $http.get('****').success(function(data, status, headers, config, response) {
                
                $scope.image1 = data[0].Images1;
                $scope.image2 = data[1].Images2;
                
            })
        }
           
    }
])
```

```html
<ion-view  title="Home" data-ng-controller="TestCtrl" data-ng-init="find()"> 
<ion-content>

<div class="list card">
  <div class="item item-image">
     <img src="{{image1}}">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="list card">
  <div class="item item-image">
     <img src="{{image2}}" >
  </div>
</div>
</ion-content> 
</ion-view >
```

console i am getting 
image1:http://res.cloudinary.com/dl34322/image/upload/q_58/v1437810617/store1.png
image2:http://res.cloudinary.com/dl34322/image/upload/q_58/v1437810617/store2.png

Answer (score 0):

Just save them in local storage, then when the app loads up if there aren't any images in local storage (first time getting the app or it got wiped for some reason) fetch the images.

set it like this:

```
 localStorage.setItem("image1",  $scope.image1);
```

fetch it like this:

```
$scope.image1FromLocalStorage = localStorage.getItem("image1");
```

Then every 10 days or whatever you want you can fetch new images from the backend and save them to local storage.

Comment: no its not like cache.every time it's coming from backend

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to implement all the rest yourself (like LRU or cache size limit and so on)  you may want to consider a more complete solution Here are 2 options:

1. Generic Ioinc Cache: https://github.com/Nodonisko/ionic-cache
2. Another kind of cache which may be more apropriate for images: https://github.com/BenBBear/ionic-cache-src

See this: [ionic 2 caching images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42245987/ionic-2-caching-images/44132547?noredirect=1#comment75294534_44132547)