# ionic 2 caching images

Tags: caching, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am writing an ionic 2 application, and want to cache images.

After long searching on the web I found these references:
https://gist.github.com/ozexpert/d95677e1fe044e6173ef59840c9c484e

https://github.com/chrisben/imgcache.js/blob/master/js/imgcache.js

I implemented the given solution, but i see that the ImgCache module does not behave as expected - **the `ImgCache.isCached` callback is never called.**

Any idea or other good solution for caching images in ionic 2?

======== UPDATE ==========

Here is the directive code I use:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input } from '@angular/core';

import ImgCache from 'imgcache.js';

@Directive({
  selector: '[image-cache]'
})
export class ImageCacheDirective {
  constructor (
    private el: ElementRef
  ) {
    // init
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    // This message is shown in console
    console.log('ImageCacheDirective *** ngOnInit: ', this.el.nativeElement.src);

    this.el.nativeElement.crossOrigin = "Anonymous"; // CORS enabling

    ImgCache.isCached(this.el.nativeElement.src, (path: string, success: any) => {
      // These message are never printed
      console.log('path - '+ path);
      console.log('success - '+ success);

      if (success) {
        // already cached
        console.log('already cached so using cached');

        ImgCache.useCachedFile(this.el.nativeElement);
      } else {
        // not there, need to cache the image
        console.log('not there, need to cache the image - ' + this.el.nativeElement.src);

        ImgCache.cacheFile(this.el.nativeElement.src, () => {
          console.log('cached file');

          // ImgCache.useCachedFile(el.nativeElement);
        });
      }
    });
  }
}
```

In **app.nodule.es** I do:

```
import { ImageCacheDirective } from '../components/image-cache-directive/image-cache-directive';
```

and then in home.html:

```
<img src="http://localhost/ionic-test/img/timeimg.php" image-cache>
```

Comment: Please add the portion of your code where you declare/use the module

Comment: I can't believe image caching is neglected by ionic community..

Answer (score 0):

It's late but probably this is the solution:

**1. Install cordova FileTransfer:**

```
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-file-transfer --save
```

**2. Init ImgCache when the deviceready event of cordova fires**. In src/app/app.component.ts add these methods (or integrate them with your initializeApp() method - this method comes up with a default project start):

```
initImgCache() {
    // activated debug mode
    ImgCache.options.debug = true;
    ImgCache.options.chromeQuota = 100 * 1024 * 1024; // 100 MB
    ImgCache.init(() => { },
        () => { console.log('ImgCache init: error! Check the log for errors'); });
}

initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        this.initImgCache();

        // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
        // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
        StatusBar.styleDefault();
        Splashscreen.hide();
    });
}
```

Comment: Why is file transfer being used and not Ionic Storage?

Comment: @VanDir  i want to cache dynamic images which are getting from firebase. in html i'm using *ngFor to loop the data. in these how can i cache images

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use a dedicated cache manager for ionic. instead of implementing everything on your own.

Here are 2 options :
1. A generic cache implementation :https://github.com/Nodonisko/ionic-cache
2. This one is better for images: https://github.com/BenBBear/ionic-cache-src

EDIT:
This is not a "link only" answer.. it tells the user to use a ready made implementations instead of trying to implement from scratch.